# ConnectionKit and SFTP: How to authenticate CK2FileManager

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sftp, connectionkit

For my Mac OS X Cocoa app, I am trying to

- connect to a SFTP server that only accepts username/password credentials
- get the contents of a remote directory
- upload files

and find it surprisingly complicated.

After trying ConnectionKit (nearly no documentation), NMSSH (crashed once too often with simultaneous uploads), rsync (not supported by the server), sftp (needs key authentication if scripted, doesn't work with username/password), I am now back to ConnectionKit: https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit

However, I am struggling with the authentication challenge, as I don’t know what to do with my credential in the delegate method.

- I downloaded and compiled ConnectionKit (apparently version 2).
- I am trying to use CK2FileManager as the [Readme](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit#readme) indicates (is this the right approach at all? Or should I use the [libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper](https://github.com/karelia/libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper) instead?… however I had troubles with libssh2 blocking methods in NMSSH before)
- I am successfully setting up my connection URL and
- my delegates' -didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is called

But this is where I struggle: I know how to create a NSURLCredential, however, I can’t figure out what to do with it =>

```
- (void)fileManager:(CK2FileManager *)manager
 didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
{
  NSURLCredential *credentials = [NSURLCredential 
    credentialWithUser:self.username
    password:[self getPassword]
    persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    // what to do now?
    // [manager useCredential:] doesn’t exist, nor is there a manager.connection?
    // ...
}
```

I already read the header, I searched the archives of this list, but all answers seem to be outdated. 
I also searched Google, Bing and StackOverflow and found one promising example from 2011 using CKFTPConnection, which doesn’t seem to be included in the current framework anymore.

Thanks so much for any pointer to the right direction.

---

### tl;dr

I don't know how to respond to ConnectionKit's CK2FileManager authenticationChallenge: 
see the comment in the code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that was easy and I could have found out that on my own; just for the reference: `[[challenge sender] useCredential:credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];`

Sorry to reward myself for my own question, but maybe this code snippet helps filling the missing docs, this is how I connect to my SFTP server with ConnectionKit:

```
- (void)connectWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void))completionBlock {
    if(!self.cFileManager) {
        self.cFileManager = [[CK2FileManager alloc] init];
        self.cFileManager.delegate = self;
    }
    NSURL *sftpServer = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"sftp://" stringByAppendingString:self.server]];
    self.remoteFolder = [CK2FileManager URLWithPath:self.remotePath relativeToURL:sftpServer];
    // try to get the contents of the current directory
    [self.cFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:self.remoteFolder
        includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
        options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
        completionHandler:^(NSArray *contents, NSError *error) 
    {
        NSLog(@"remote folder contents: \n%@", contents);
    // invoke completion block
    completionBlock();
    }];
}



- (void)fileManager:(CK2FileManager *)manager
 didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge 
{
    NSURLCredential *credentials = [NSURLCredential 
      credentialWithUser:self.username
      password:[self getPassword]
      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For CK2:

```
- (void)listDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path
{
    // path is here   @"download"
    NSURL *ftpServer = [NSURL URLWithString:@"sftp://companyname.topLevelDomain"];
    NSURL *directory = [CK2FileManager URLWithPath:path isDirectory:YES hostURL:ftpServer];

    CK2FileManager *fileManager = [[CK2FileManager alloc] init];
    fileManager.delegate = self;

    [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:directory
               includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
                                  options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                        completionHandler:^(NSArray *contents, NSError *error) {
                            if (!error) {
                                NSLog(@"%@", contents);
                            } else {
                                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                            }
                        }];

}
```

and than you have to implement the following protocol

```
- (void)fileManager:(CK2FileManager *)manager operation:(CK2FileOperation *)operation
didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 completionHandler:(void (^)(CK2AuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential *credential))completionHandler
{
    if (![challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault]) {
        completionHandler(CK2AuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling, nil);
        return;
    }

    NSString * username = @"<username>";
    NSString * pathToPrivateSSHKey = @"</Users/myNameOnLocalMaschine/.ssh/id_rsa>"

    NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential ck2_credentialWithUser:username
                                                       publicKeyURL:nil
                                                      privateKeyURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToPrivateSSHKey]
                                                           password:nil
                                                        persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    completionHandler(CK2AuthChallengeUseCredential, cred);

}
```

That's it.

Call `-listDirectoryAtPath:` and then you will get in the Completion Handler Block in contents array all the files located on the given path :)